# Change Approval Statu of List Items After x Days

Tags: workflow, 2013

I want to make list items Approval Status "Pending" again, after 60 days since it was created. I don't want to delete it. How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a workflow created for this? Could you elaborate the question?

Comment: I have a workflow for this list to approve the items. It works fine. But I also want to change the statu of the Aproval Statu after 60 days. I think I have to do it with workflow because approval statu is a parameter of workflow.